# jQuery.load() responds with error under Firefox, works fine under Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome, firefox

I have a function to open a page in a dialog box instead of the main window. A bit cleaned up code is the following:

```
var baseurl = window.location.origin + '/static/docs/'

function onClickLink(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if ($("#dialog").length == 0) {
    setUpDialog()
  }
  var href = event.target.href;
  href = baseurl + href.substring(1 + href.lastIndexOf('/'));
  $("#dialog").load(href + ' .body', function(response, status, xhr) {
    if (status == "error") {
      window.location = event.target.href;
    } else {
      changeImageSrc();
      reStructure();
    }
  });
  $("#dialog").dialog({
    modal: true,
    title: event.target.text,
    width: 960,
    position: ['center', 100]
  });
}
```

This code works fine in Chrome, but the (status == "error") is executed under Firefox. Seemingly there is a 404 error for Firefox, might be an image of the loaded page, or something similar.

Any ideas how to get the Chrome behavior under Firefox too?
(you can find a working [example here](http://openerp.co.hu/hu/funkcionalis-bemutato/))

Comment: Carry out an alert() on baseurl to test the variable is the same value on both browsers

Comment: `window.location.origin` is undefined.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. In FireFox, window.location.origin is `undefined`. FireFox therefore tires to get the page:

   `http://openerp.co.hu/hu/funkcionalis-bemutato/undefined/static/docs/sales.html`

   and fails
2. In chrome, window.location.origin `http://openerp.co.hu`. Chrome ties to get the page:

   `http://openerp.co.hu/static/docs/sales.html`

   and succeeds

Instead of relying on `window.location.origin`, try using:

```
window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host
```

Comment: or instead stay relying on `location.origin` with `if(location.origin!=undefined) location.origin = location.protocol + "//" + location.host`

Answer (score 1):

[why firefox doesn't support window.location.origin](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/history.html#dom-location) (it's not standard)

## tl;dr

sometimes you need this instead of the previously selected answer:

```
var $window_location_origin = window.location.protocol+'//'+window.location.host;
```

## explanation

I need to get the length of `window.location.origin` aka `window.location.protocol+'//'+window.location.host`. Simply replacing the former with the latter, doesn't work.

`window.location.protocol+'//'+window.location.host.length` will return something like `http://25`, which is the protocol and the length of `window.location.host` concatenated on the end.

I got around this by making a variable, like so:

```
var $window_location_origin = window.location.protocol+'//'+window.location.host;
```

After that, I could get the length of `$window_location_origin` which would be that original 25 (`window.location.host.length`) plus the 7 from `window.location.protocol+'//'`, giving me the desired 32.

Comment: I don't get your point at all why didn't you just use `(window.location.protocol+'//'+window.location.host).length` ?

Comment: ...'cause I'm a dummy. and I believe I needed that variable for some reason later on. Maybe I'll revisit when I have time. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Any error message in particular? Also, update your code with the ones below:

```
var baseurl = window.location.origin  + '/static/docs/';

function onClickLink(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    if($("#dialog").length==0) {
        setUpDialog();
    }

    var href = event.target.href;

    href = baseurl + href.substring(1+href.lastIndexOf('/'));

    $("#dialog").load(href + ' .body', function(response, status, xhr) {
      if (status == "error") {
        window.location = event.target.href;
      } else {
        changeImageSrc();
        reStructure();
      }
    });

    $("#dialog").dialog({
        modal:true, 
        title:event.target.text,
        width: 960,
        position: ['center', 100]
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

404 means "page not found".

Set a breakpoint and check the URL which causes the problem. Is it really valid?

Maybe Chrome is more lenient when it comes to illegal characters in the URL than Firefox or something like that. Try to paste the URL into a location bar in both browsers to see what you get.